# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage.util.montage'

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to import `montage2d` module from scikit-image:

`from skimage.util.montage import montage2d`

But this error popped up:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage.util.montage'`

I'm pretty sure I installed the scikit-image package as:

`pip install scikit-image` (0.14.0)

I also tried Anaconda:

`conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image` (0.14.0)

Build from source doesn't work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `scikit-image=0.14.0` `skimage.util.montage.` namespace has been removed, `montage2d` function has been deprecated and moved to `skimage.util.montage2d`.

For more info, see the release notes for the version `0.14.0` - https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/doc/release/release_0.14.rst.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Problem solved with `from skimage.util import montage2d`. Should have read the release notes.

Comment: Solved with `pip install scikit-image==0.13.1`

Comment: version 0.17.2 solved with ```from skimage.util import montage ```

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of editing from a lot of lines, I used to import in this manner,

```
from skimage.util import montage as montage2d
```

Also, you can change the version as [described above.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689353/13621630)