# How import module in python

Tags: python, import, module, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to import montage2d module from scikit-image:

`from skimage.util.montage import montage2d`

But this error popped up:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage.util.montage'`

I'm pretty sure I installed the scikit-image package as:

`pip install scikit-image (0.18.1)`
I'm trying `pip install scikit-image==0.13.1` but it failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6VWu.png)

Comment: Did you look at this [modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-skimage-util-montage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684500/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-skimage-util-montage)?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from skimage.util import montage
```

Or, with older versions:

```
pip install scikit-image==0.13.1

from skimage.util.montage import montage2d
```

Comment: I'm trying to import montage2d module from scikit-image:                                                  
 from skimage.util import montage2d                                                                                cannot import name 'montage2d' from 'skimage.util

Comment: I edited, in your version it seems to have been replaced by montage. If you really want montage2d, then use pip install scikit-image==0.13.1 and your original syntax

Comment: I tried to download this version pip install scikit-image==0.13.1 but it failed

Comment: it failed is not really informative, what is the log message? try to pip uninstall scikit-image before

Comment: " Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-image
  Building wheel for scikit-image (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: Partial import of skimage during the build process.
  Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built geometry.c
  Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built transform.c.......etc "

Comment: pip install Cython

Comment: I downloaded cython ... but my problem was not resolved

Comment: Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-image
  Building wheel for scikit-image (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\wasim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =

Comment: Running setup.py clean for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
Installing collected packages: scikit-image
    Running setup.py install for scikit-image ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\wasim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\wasim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-ins